# Importing data from main.py to example.py not working properly

Tags: python, class, object, import

I can't seem to be able to import allot of the data correctly. For example my script is a simple GUI with a main.py and ipfunc.py the main.py file contains the TKinter GUI code and the ipfunc.py file contains all the functions that each button will perform.

I had this code working perfectly in the older version with all the code put together not using classes and objects for the GUI, however now i'm having allot of trouble trying to import data from file to file.

**This is the GUI (main.py) file**

```
from ipfunc import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import tkinter as tk


class gui:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        root.title("IPPing")
        root.geometry("380x100+900+300")

        self.label = Label(root, text="___________").grid(row=1)
        self.label2 = Label(root, text="Enter IP Address").grid(row=2)

        e1 = tk.Entry(root)
        e1.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.button_addip = Button(text='Add New IP', command=newip).grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2)
        self.button_list = Button(root, text='List of IPs', command=contents).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.SE,
                                                                                    pady=2)
        self.button_ping = Button(root, text='Ping all servers', command=scanlist).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.SE,
                                                                                         pady=2)
        self.button_quit = Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).grid(row=0, column=3, pady=2)


root = tk.Tk()
ip_gui = gui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This is the functions that i want to execute when buttons are pressed, but theirs errors when using the functions that i cant solve it, please help.

https://gist.github.com/Hontiris1/83c8229313d971214d8610c21fe2e676

Comment: [Edit] your question and show your Tracback. You want to use `e1` which is `local` to `__init__` in `module ipfunc`. **THATS NOT POSSIBLE**

Comment: how do i make it not local